# WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, web-services, sockets, exception

I have a client application that uses WebHttpRequest to get response from external server, it works fine but some times I'm getting the following exception ....

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to
>   connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A
>   connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond
>   xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxx    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint
>   endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress
>   socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint
>   remoteEP)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean
>   connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6,
>   Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception&
>   exception)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---
>
> at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext&
>   context)
>
> at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

.... Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more of a "Request Timed Out" error. The server you are trying to connect to did not respond to your request. You should handle this exception using try-catch and attempt to connect *n* number of times again in the catch block.

Comment: I tried by increasing the timeout too, but not solved. It works for a number of requests but in the middle of many successful transaction, this exception is raised and has no time or number of transaction failing pattern.

Comment: Now i'm getting a specific error 
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest).
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: It seems like the server is the problem, not your code. The server may require certain options to be set during the connection.

Comment: thanks Evan. yeah it looks on their side (webserver) not in the client code.